# IdeaVim : Navigate through project file

Tags: android-studio, vim, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim

Is it possible with the plugin IdeaVim for IntelliJ to navigate thourgh project file (in the window below) using hjkl key ? Like the CtrlP plugin for Vim.

[image]

Comment: No, that plugin only deals with text editing. But you can probably send them a feature request.

Comment: I **heard** that, navigating through files in the left side window is not efficient as `ctrl-(shift)-n`

Comment: I always use ctrl-n but when dealing with large projects it's hard to remember all the file name.. Do you know if there is a plugin for this behavior ?

Comment: Navigate by symbols, not by filenames.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2021, this is now possible.

All you have to do is enable the NERDTree plugin in ideavim by inserting `set NERDTree` into your .ideavimrc

Comment: I didn't know. I have NERDTree on my `.vimrc` and it worked perfectly. The custom binding I have toggles the pane and when opening it moves the focus there so I can navigate the files. Cool.

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 3):

if you're looking for a CtrlP equivalent, Webstorm has a fuzzy finder that's actually much more powerful than CtrlP.
Try COMMAND+SHIFT+O (the letter O) on Mac or CTRL+SHIFT+N on Windows/Linux.

There is more here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html?origin=old_help#d937859e425

Answer (score 1):

This is old but just in case anyone is looking for marginal efficiency. I use [this](https://github.com/KyleScharnhorst/AhkCapsLocksRemap) AutoHotKey script to achieve this exact behavior - together with as you'll figure other mapping for never needing to travel out to the Numpad, Arrow keys or Special keys.

As it is a very short repo here are the essentials:

> 1. Download autohotkey (https://autohotkey.com/).
> 2. Place the .ahk script into the startup folder (win + r, then run "shell:startup" to find on Windows) (https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Startup). This allows the script to always be active, as it is ran on startup.
> 3. Run the Script to go into effect now.

The script is:

```
#SingleInstance
+CapsLock::CapsLock
CapsLock::Esc
```

Its been game changing